# Understanding the following environment entry in manifest.yml pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have this `manifest.yml`:

```yaml
applications:
- name: xx
  buildpack: java-bp480-v2
  instances: 2
  memory: 2G
  path: webapp/build/libs/trid.war
  services:
   - xxservice
   - xxservice
   - xxcktbrkrcnfgsvc
   - xxappdynamics
   - autoscaler-xx
env:
   spring_profiles_active: cloud
   swagger_active: false
   JAVA_OPTS: -Dspring.profiles.active=cloud -Xmx1G -Xms1G -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

What will `env` do?.
Will that create three environment variables or it will append `JAVA_OPTS` to the start command if the spring profile active is cloud?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will env do?.

The env block will instruct the cf cli to create environment variables on your behalf. Entries take the form `variable_name: variable_value`. From your example, you'll end up with a variable named `spring_profiles_active` with a value of `cloud`. Plus the other two you have defined.

`JAVA_OPTS` is a special env variable for the Java buildpack. Whatever you put into JAVA_OPTS will be included in the start command for your application. It is an easy way to add additional arguments, system properties and configuration flags to the JVM.

Please note, at least in the example above, the spacing is wrong on your `env:` block`. It's all the way to the left, but the` env:`should be indented two spaces. Then each env variable defined under the`env:` block should be indented two more spaces for a total of four spaces. YAML is very picky about spaces and indentation. When in doubt, use a YAML validator to confirm your YAML is valid.